# I have a minor issue with my dropdown menu when switching pages

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have a small issue with my dropdown menu when switching to another page. When I press my menu label button, the navigation bar slides down and when I then proceed to another page the dropdown menu acts if it was open but it is not so when I press the menu label button again the navigation bar slides up instead of down and after that it works normally.

**What do I do to make the slide bar return to normal state when I switch pages?**
I hope you understand what I mean, otherwise I will try to clarify

**HTML**

```
<nav id="navBar">
    <ul id="mainNav">
        <li class="hem"><a href="index.html">Hem</a></li>
        <li><a href="kontakt.html">Kontakt</a></li>
        <li><a href="om.html">Om</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
#navBar {
    display:none;
    position:relative;

}

#navBar.active{
    display:block;
    height:auto;

}

#mainNav {

    background:#202020;

}

#mainNav li {
    padding:6px 0;
}

#mainNav a {
    color:white;
    font-weight:bold;

}

#mainNav li:hover {
    background-color:#f3ba32;

}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$("#menulabel").click(function() {
    $("#navBar").toggleClass("active").slideToggle(300);

});
```

Comment: Are you loading your content via Ajax or are you reloading the whole page?

Comment: Reloading the whole page I would assume, I haven't used anything with Ajax unless it is standard

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't tried this already, would simply resetting it at every page load work for you?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#navBar").removeClass("active");
});
```

Also, are you sure you want to use click for this behavior? Have you looked at simply using hover?

[jquery menu hovering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9184988/jquery-menu-hovering)

http://api.jquery.com/hover/

[Jquery menu with sub menu hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18636908/jquery-menu-with-sub-menu-hover)